# Agregar datos a una List con un List <float>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola que tal buenas tardes compañeros tengo un problema que llevo con el todo el día.

Tengo una clase llamada tipo datos que contiene un string Nombre y una lista tipo float Total.

```
public class datos
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public List<float> Total{get;set;}
    }
```

Ahora tengo un Webmethod que es llamado por Ajax y le regreso una lista de tipo datos

Mi metodo es

```
//datoPorSemana es una lista Global 
static IList datoPorSemana = new List<datos>();
[WebMethod]
    public static IList busca(List<string> pData)
    {
        datoPorSemana.Clear();

        datoPorSemana.Add(new datos
                        {

                            Nombre= "Nombre ",
                            Total.Add(3),
                            Total.Add(5),
                            Total.Add(1),
                        }); 
        return datoPorSemana;
    }
```

Ahora mi problema es este mi variable Total de la clase datos no es de un tamaño fijo asi como puedo meter un dato puedo meter n datos, como hago para hacerlo??? me gustaría que quedara de la siguiente forma mi WebMethod

```
static IList datoPorSemana = new List<datos>();
[WebMethod]
    public static IList busca(List<string> pData)
    {
        datoPorSemana.Clear();
        list<float> aux = new list<float>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            aux.Add(i)
        }
        datoPorSemana.Add(new datos
                        {

                            Nombre= "Nombre ",
                            Total.Add(new List<float>(aux)),
                        }); 
        return datoPorSemana;
    }
```

O si tienen Alguna otra forma de llenar un arreglo de float en una lista tambien es recibido,pero si es importante que mi variable Total sea un arreglo de float

Saludos.

Comment: Reemplaza `List<float[]>` por `List<float>`. ¿Por qué necesitas llenar un arreglo de float en una lista de tipo float[]?.

Comment: Si ya eh corregido mi codigo ahora lo que sucede es que me sale el siguiente error  "Declarador de miembro de inicializador no válido" en la Linea de Total.Add(new List<float>(aux))

Comment: Usa `Total.Add(aux)` en lugar de `Total.Add(new List<float>(aux))`. En la modificación de tu código, estableciste que `List<float>`. No entiendo porqué colocas `new List<float>(aux)`.

Comment: Eso use en un principio "Total.Add(aux)" pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error "Declarador de miembro de inicializador no válido", es por eso que pense que tendría que crear la nueva instancia de List<float> pero con ambos sale el error

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes, quizá no logro entender el alcance, sin embargo aquí dejo un ejemplo.

En mi ejemplo muestro el Nombre y un Total, recuerda que como el total esta en un arreglo y dentro de una lista se debe ingresar [posición x][posición y]

Clase

```
    public class Datos
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public List<float[]> Total { get; set; };

        public Datos()
        {
            Nombre = string.Empty;
            Total = new List<float[]>();
        }
    }
```

Metodo

```
    static IList<Datos> datoPorSemana = new List<Datos>();
    //Recibo como parametro los totales
    public IList<Datos> busca(List<float> pData)
    {
        datoPorSemana.Clear();
        float[] aux = new float[pData.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < pData.Count; i++)
        {
            aux[i] = pData[i];
        }
        Datos d = new Datos();
        d.Nombre = "Nombre";
        d.Total.Add(aux);
        datoPorSemana.Add(d);

        return datoPorSemana;
    }
```

Implementación

```
static IList<Datos> resul = new List<Datos>();

public void Main()
{
    //Son los datos por semana que me imagino seran ingresados
    List<float> valores = new List<float>{10,20,30,40};

    resul = busca(valores);

    //Itero la lista de Datos que se han generado
    foreach(var a in resul)
    {
        //Muestro los resultados. en a.Total estoy ingresando la posicion en donde se encuentra el total
        //Recuerda que como el total esta en un arreglo y dentro de una lista se debe ingresar [posicion x][posicion y] 
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " +  a.Nombre + " Totales: " +  a.Total[0][1]);
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón no se  por que no lo hice de esa manera muchas gracias fue de gran ayuda. Saludos

Comment: @ErnestoZarateJurado acepta la respuesta por favor, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio :)